# Python create many-to-many relationships from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list, say `terms = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

Which is the best way to create a list-of-lists or list-of-tuples of many-to-many relationships like this;

```
[['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','C'],['B','D'],['C','D']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

list(combinations(terms, r=2))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> terms = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> list(combinations(terms, r=2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

These are tuples, not lists, but that's easily remedied if that is a problem:

```
>>> map(list, combinations(terms, r=2))
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]
```